# Why doesn't XML allow nesting of comments

Tags: xml

Is there any particular reason (other than it would make the parsing harder) that XML doesn't allow nesting comments, i.e. something like

```
<!--
  <!-- this is the foo element -->
  <foo>bar</foo>
-->
```

?

Comment: If it allowed that, it would prevent you from just putting `<!--` in a comment, wouldn't it?

Comment: How should a parser treat `<foo>bar</foo>` here?

Comment: @JonSkeet Is that really an important concern for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, it's for the same reason that you can't nest tags:

```
<tag1 <tag2>foo</tag2>>  <!-- This won't work. -->
```

<strike>A comment is really just one kind of tag, and the same rules apply to comments as to any other  tag.</strike>

**Update:** Quentin properly points out that a comment is, in fact, *not* a tag. [It's a different thing altogether.](http://www.jelks.nu/XML/xmlebnf.html) What *is* true, though, is that comments follow the same delimiter-content-delimeter pattern that tags do. Compare the rule for comments (15) to the rule for empty tags (44) and the rules for start tags (40, 41), and contrast those with the rule for elements (39). Elements *can* be nested (43), but an element is (back to 39) a start_tag-content-end_tag combination where the content part can be an element. A comment, again, *works like* an individual tag, not like an element.

Now, all that explains *that* comments can't be nested, but not *why* it was designed that way. I don't know enough about the history of XML to say what was in the hearts of its designers, but XML is "an application" of the even more general SGML. It was also developed well after the introduction of HTML and was intended in part to address some of the flaws in HTML. SGML and HTML [share the same syntax for comments](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/comments.html), and it's obvious just by looking that XML inherited that same syntax. One has to imagine, then, that XML comments work they way they do largely because they were inherited from its predecessors: the decision had been made before XML development even got underway.

Comment: A comment is not a kind of tag, even if it superficially looks like one.

Answer (score 4):

It would have been entirely possible to allow nested comments, without changing the syntax. The designers of XML chose not to because they were greatly concerned with SGML compatibility: it would have allowed XML documents that were not valid SGML documents.

Answer (score 2):

Because `<! >` is the syntax for a markup declaration and `--` is the syntax for the start and end of a comment.

You can't nest comments because the syntax to start one is the same as the syntax to close one.

Comment: Weird. Very weird. However I think the question was more akin to "why is it designed this way", not "what is the technical reason it doesn't work that way as designed". Or at least that's what I want to know. :P

Answer (score 1):

The opening comment tag comments out everything it sees (including more opening comment tags) until it reaches the first closing comment tag.  After that, the comment is over and any remaining closing comment tags will not be recognized.  Same as HTML.